# Dropping unique constraint for column in H2

Tags: sql, database, h2

I try to drop unique constraint for column in h2, previously created as `info varchar(255) unique`.

I tried:

```
sql> alter table public_partner drop constraint (select distinct unique_index_name from in
formation_schema.constraints where table_name='PUBLIC_PARTNER' and column_list='INFO');
```

But with no success (as follows):

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE PUBLIC_PARTNER DROP CONSTRAINT ([*]SELECT DISTI
NCT UNIQUE_INDEX_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME='PUBLIC_PARTNER
' AND COLUMN_LIST='INFO') "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
alter table public_partner drop constraint (select distinct unique_index_name from informa
tion_schema.constraints where table_name='PUBLIC_PARTNER' and column_list='INFO') [42001-1
60]
```

How this constraint should be correctly removed?

By the way:

```
sql> (select unique_index_name from information_schema.constraints where table_name='PUBLI
C_PARTNER' and column_list='INFO');
UNIQUE_INDEX_NAME
CONSTRAINT_F574_INDEX_9
(1 row, 0 ms)
```

seems to return a correct output.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the SQL language, identifier names can't be expressions. You need to run two statements:

```
select distinct constraint_name from information_schema.constraints 
where table_name='PUBLIC_PARTNER' and column_list='INFO'
```

and then get the identifier name, and run the statement

```
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC_PARTNER DROP CONSTRAINT <xxx>
```

Comment: Thanks, Thomas! I expected you personally to answer to my question :) The problem is that your solution is obvious for me, and i will accept your answer anyway as useful. The bad thing is i need it to automate my delta script without manual intervention :(((

Comment: With this I got "Constraint <xxx> not found". It worked for me with "constraint_name" instead of "unique_index_name", so that the select was `select distinct constraint_name from in formation_schema.constraints 
where table_name='PUBLIC_PARTNER' and column_list='INFO'`

One may also additionally restrict the constraint type by adding ` AND  constraint_type = 'UNIQUE'`

My H2 version was 1.3.166 btw.

Comment: @MartinGrotzke Thanks! I have updated my answer (there was also a typo in "information_schema").

Comment: This is just what I need, and I'm so close... You glossed over how to get the identifier name, and I'm having a very hard time figuring it out (I'm using H2).

Answer (score 7):

You could use a user defined function to execute a dynamically created statement. First to create the `execute` alias (only once):

```
CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS EXECUTE AS $$ void executeSql(Connection conn, String sql) 
throws SQLException { conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(sql); } $$;
```

Then to call this method:

```
call execute('ALTER TABLE PUBLIC_PARTNER DROP CONSTRAINT ' || 
    (select distinct unique_index_name from in formation_schema.constraints 
    where table_name='PUBLIC_PARTNER' and column_list='INFO'));
```

... where `execute` is the user defined function that runs a statement.

Comment: This would be the user defined function:  

    `CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS EXECUTE AS $$
    void executeSql(Connection conn, String sql) throws SQLException {
        conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(sql);
    }
    $$;`

Comment: using this solution but it's failing with `Feature not supported: "VARCHAR +"; SQL statement:`. My Code: `call execute('ALTER TABLE DAILY_AGGREGATES DROP CONSTRAINT '+
 (select distinct constraint_name from information_schema.constraints  where table_name='DAILY_AGGREGATES' and constraint_type='PRIMARY KEY'));`

Comment: In SQL, the `+` is not used for concatenating string. Instead, use `||`. As in: `call execute('ALTER TABLE DAILY_AGGREGATES DROP CONSTRAINT ' || (select distinct constraint_name from information_schema.constraints where table_name='DAILY_AGGREGATES' and constraint_type='PRIMARY KEY'));`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using H2 with Spring Boot in **PosgreSQL Mode** the query has to include the schema `public` and the tables are likely in lower case mode. (see `application.yml` below)

Check the letter case in the information schema table and **use the upper and lower case as seen in table `information_schema.constraints`**.

#### Verbose Query Set

```
SET @constraint_name = QUOTE_IDENT(
              SELECT DISTINCT constraint_name
              FROM information_schema.constraints
              WHERE table_schema = 'public'
              AND table_name = 'public_partner'
              AND constraint_type = 'UNIQUE'
              AND column_list = 'info');

SET @command = 'ALTER TABLE public.public_partner DROP CONSTRAINT public.' || @constraint_name;

SELECT @command;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE @command;
```

Explanation:

- SELECT DISTINCT constraint_name [...]

  Select the Columns constraint_name with the UNIQUE constrain from the schema info
- QUOTE_IDENT([...])

  I don't know why this is needed, it will quote the resulting string
- SET @constraint_name = [...];

  Store in Variable @constraint_name
- SET @command = [...];

  Compose whole command by concatenation of strings and store in variable @command
- SELECT @command;

  Show the composed Query on Screen, just for debugging
- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE @command;

  Execute @command

Typical H2 Configuration in **PostgreSQL Mode** in the Spring Boot `application.yml` (extract)

```yaml
spring:
  # [...]
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  # [...]
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false
    username: sa
    password: sa
  # [...]
```