# Drop/Insert constraint using Liquibase and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, constraints, liquibase, migrate

I'm new to Liquibase + Hibernate.

I have a table named Users, with columns {Id, FirstName, LastName, YearOfBirth, .....}. 
I set with Hibernate annotation a unique constraint for the couple {Id, LastName}.

Now, I decided that I want to update the constraint, to include the FirstName column, meaning I want my unique constraint to be {Id, FirstName, LastName}. 
Can this be done through Liquibase, on my existing db, through a changeset?

I thought about dropping the old constraint through a changeset, and creating the new constraint with another. The problem is, I don't know the name of the old constraint, neither the names of the indexes following it. And since Liquibase/Hibernate auto-generate names for the constraints/indexes, I don't want to search through a query to fetch the specific constraint name.

I'm searching for a solution that is more generic, so I can tackle same future issues.

Any suggestions?

I'm using Java 8, Hibernate 5.2.10, Liquibase 3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the index name is a required field when dropping it. Here is the relevant documentation from [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/drop_index.html).

In this case, you will need to drop the index using SQL commands. Depending on what the underlying database is, you will need to programmatically figure out the name of the index assigned to the table that you would like to drop, based on the column names of the index. For example, if you are using Oracle database you could run the SQL explained [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/indexes_for_table_query.htm) and capture these commands in a sql file. Liquibase supports including SQL files as changesets, so you will need to use the sqlFile tag in your changeSet as explained [here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql_file.html) so that the sql statements that you captured earlier is run. Once the index is dropped, you could use the liquibase changeSet again to add a new index/constraint as needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I already had checked your recommendations about the sql-tag.

As for the db type, I'm using H2. Didn't find a way so far to do the above. Anything you might know?

Comment: Here is a post about finding constraints in H2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008476/dropping-unique-constraint-for-column-in-h2

Answer (score 0):

Some notes for the future:

You can set a unique constraint name by this way:

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = 
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "unique_field" }, name = "UK_users_unique_field")
```

I think, you shouldn't create a schema by the Hibernate, if you want to use Liquibase. You need to create a schema by Liquibase with your SQL scripts. You can generate a SQL script by Hibernate of course.

Use

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
```

to validate a database schema only, without creating anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried re-creating the schema db, by generating the changelog through Liquibase.

I noticed that the constraints and indexes had a random auto-generated name, so I renamed them to suit my needs.

The problem is, that for some indexes/constraints, athough my changesets added, Hibernate also created the same indexes for some cases, but again with a random name.

Any input on that?

Comment: I found what the problem was.. I was setting in my hibernate.cfg.xml file: 

<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

so some indexes and constraints were created by Liquibase **and** by Hibernate. I removed the hbm2ddl property, and everything works now!

@v.ladynev with the `validate` value, the database schema will be validated by which criteria?

Comment: @Dionysis Hibernate will compare entities with a database schema during initialization. So you will have all schema inconsistencies before application start.